# How to get role of user

Tags: user-roles

I need to get the role associated with a user -- not the "currently logged in user".

I am using Buddypress (not that should matter to the nature of this question) and I am in the `bp_members()` loop.

How can I retrieve the role of the user I am reporting on in the loop at any given time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Use the user ID and [`WP_User`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User):

```
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
print wp_sprintf_l( '%l', $user->roles );
```

### Update

```
/**
 * Get user roles by user ID.
 *
 * @param  int $id
 * @return array
 */
function wpse_58916_user_roles_by_id( $id )
{
    $user = new WP_User( $id );

    if ( empty ( $user->roles ) or ! is_array( $user->roles ) )
        return array ();

    $wp_roles = new WP_Roles;
    $names    = $wp_roles->get_names();
    $out      = array ();

    foreach ( $user->roles as $role )
    {
        if ( isset ( $names[ $role ] ) )
            $out[ $role ] = $names[ $role ];
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Usage example:

```
print '<pre>' 
    . htmlspecialchars( 
        print_r( wpse_58916_user_roles_by_id(1), TRUE ) 
        ) 
    . '</pre>';

Array
(
    [administrator] => Administrator
)
```

Comment: Thanks @toscho -- it didn't seem to get me what I was expecting. I got an editor, a blank/null value, and bbp_participant. I was expecting to see Admin, Editor, Author or Subscriber as those are the only roles we are using.

Comment: @frank13 See my update.

Comment: Thanks @toscho ... that's a lot of code to get a data value I would have thought would have been more readily available.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!  So sad, and confusing, why you can't access the user's role more directly.  The "can user" function functions the opposite of what most people would want.

Answer (score 7):

If `bp_members` returns an array of `WP_User` objects, each should have a the property `roles` that contains an array of the users roles.

Otherwise, you can use `get_user_meta` for the key `wp_capabilities`, which will return an array of `role => capability` pairs:

```
<?php
$caps = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'wp_capabilities', true);
$roles = array_keys((array)$caps);
```

Comment: $roles ends up being an array. I am looking to get the `$user->ID`'s role. Only one role as no users in our system are assigned more than 1 role.

Comment: `$roles[0]`, done.

Comment: Ok, thanks @ChristopherDavis ... $roles[0] returns "0" across the board for every user in the list

Comment: @chrisguitarguy does $roles[0] work still?

Comment: `$roles = reset(array_keys((array)$caps));`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, it probably changed over the years, now it's not `'wp_capabilities'`. I looked at the core WP files, how they do it now, and found a new solution to this. Here's the code I use now:

```
global $wpdb;
$cap = get_user_meta( $wp_user_id, $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'capabilities', true );
```

`$cap` then comes as an associative array, for example:

```
{
    "administrator": true
}
```

or

```
{
    "subscriber": true
}
```

So in your case you should probably then get the keys of the array:

```
$caps_array = array_keys( $cap );
```

and then get everything from it. I needed to see if the user has the administrator role, so I checked:

```
if ( is_array( $cap ) && !empty( $cap['administrator'] ) ) { return true; }
```

I had a user ID, not the whole `WP_User` object, and I didn't want to use any solution that would create the `user` object. As I checked, `get_user_meta` goes straight to the db to check for this exact parameter, so this should be the fastest and resource-wise route.